# Problema com Troca de Imagens por Interação ao usuario em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou desenvolvendo uma código para interação com usuário, na qual ele deve acender uma lâmpada ao passar o mouse por cima, e quebrá-la caso `click` sobre ela.

A iteração de `hover` esta ocorrendo normalmente, mas a de `click` não funciona no *IE*, *Chrome*.

Alguém pode ajudar?

```js
function MudaLampada(tipo) {
  if (tipo == 1) {
    arquivo = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxlO.jpg";
  }
  if (tipo == 2) {
    arquivo = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxlO.jpg";
  }
  if (tipo == 3) {
    arquivo = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRjsF.jpg";
  }
  document.getElementById("luz").src = arquivo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Teste Javascript</title>
      <script>
        function MudaLampada(tipo) {
          if (tipo == 1) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
          }
          if (tipo == 2) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
          }
          if (tipo == 3) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";
          }
          document.getElementById("luz").src = arquivo;
        }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Acenda a Lampada</h1>
      <img src="_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg" id="luz" onmousemove="MudaLampada(1)" onmouseout="MudaLampada(2)" onclick="MudaLampada(3)" />
    </body>

    </html>
```

[image: Lampada Apagada]
[image: Lampada Quebrada]
[image: Lampada Acesa]

Comment: Em que versão do IE não funciona?

Comment: No IE ele esta funcionando só não está nos outros porem ele da um certo bug no IE tbm

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o evento "onclick" dispara junto com "onmousemove". 
Precisaria adicionar alguma lógica para evitar chamar **MudaLampada(1)** depois que alguém chamar **MudaLampada(3)**.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o problema seja causado pelo `mousemove` após o clique na imagem, como apontado pelo [Fabricio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30720/fabricio-catae).

Uma alternativa é utilizar CSS para alternar as imagens da lâmpada acesa/apagada com o evento básico de **`:hover`**. E então utilizar Javascript somente para inserir uma classe responsável por alterar a imagem e mostrar a lâmpada quebrada no evento de **`click`**, por exemplo:

```js
/**
 * Quando clicado, adicionará a classe 'broken' (caso ela não esteja
 * presente), do contrário ela será removida.
 **/
document.querySelector('.lamp').addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('broken');
}, false);
```

```css
.lamp {
    height: 220px;
    width:  169px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b983w.jpg); /* apagada */
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.lamp:hover {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxlO.jpg)  /* acesa */
}

.lamp.broken {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRjsF.jpg)  /* quebrada */
}
```

```html
<h1>Acenda a lampada</h1>
<div class='lamp'></div>
```

Lembrando que nem todos os navegadores suportam [**`classlist`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), como pode ser [visto nesse *link*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). Mas [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/4056678)<sup>(en)</sup> existem algumas formas de manipular as classes em um elemento.

Answer (score 3):

A lógica que te falta é que quando a lâmpada parte já não faz sentido usar o `mousemove`. Na verdade `mousemove` é o evento errado para isso pois dispara vezes demais, tu só precisas saber se está em cima do elemento ou não.

SUgiro usares `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, e mudar a lógica para:

HTML

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b983w.jpg" id="luz" />
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){

    var inteira = true;
    var img = document.getElementById("luz");
    var estado = {
        click: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRjsF.jpg',
        mouseenter: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxlO.jpg',
        mouseleave: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/b983w.jpg'
    };

    img.addEventListener('click', mudaLampada);
    img.addEventListener('mouseenter', mudaLampada);
    img.addEventListener('mouseleave', mudaLampada);

    function mudaLampada(evento) {
        if (!inteira) return; // se já estiver partida nõ fazer nada
        if (evento.type == 'click') inteira = false; // marcar como partida
        img.src = estado[evento.type];
    }

})();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mL6c9y7r/

Answer (score -1):

```js
/*Cara o seu foi colocar essas chave dentro da function, olha o seu erro:*/



 if (tipo == 1) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
          }
          if (tipo == 2) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
          }
          if (tipo == 3) {
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";
          }


/*Dentro função, você abriu e fechou chave, essa: {}
esse foi o seu erro, o código é executado dentro da função, então deve ser escrito da seguinte forma:*/

if (tipo == 1) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
if (tipo == 2) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
if (tipo == 3) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";


/*Pois você está executando um comando dentro de uma função, então seu código deve ficar assim:*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Teste Javascript</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>
var quebrada = false;
function mudaLampada(tipo) {
if (tipo == 1) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
if (tipo == 2) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
if (tipo == 3) 
arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";
if (!quebrada)
document.getElementById("luz").src = arquivo;
if (tipo == 3) 
quebrada = true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Acenda a lâmpada</h1>
<img src="_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg" id="luz" onmousemove="mudaLampada(1)" onmouseout="mudaLampada(2)" onclick="mudaLampada(3)"/>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score -2):

/*Acho que com esse modelo de interação seria legal */

const turnOn = document.getElementById('turnOn');
const turnOff = document.getElementById('turnOff');

const lamp = document.getElementById('lamp');

function lampOn () {
lamp.src = './img/lampada-ligada.jpeg';
}

function lampOff () {
lamp.src = './img/lampada.jpeg';

}

function lampBroken() {
lamp.src = './img/lampada-quebrada.jpeg';
}

function lampFixed(){
lamp.src = './img/lampada.jpeg';
}

turnOn.addEventListener('click', lampOn) ;
turnOff.addEventListener('click', lampOff);
lamp.addEventListener('dblclick',lampBroken);
lamp.addEventListener('click',lampFixed);

Comment: Isso não soluciona o problema proposto pelo autor da pergunta. Veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour]